# Complex string replacing

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

I'm working on a project where I receive some data that is not completely how I want it and have to edit it before using. It comes in following format:

```
"((123.456 456.321 789.123, 1122.1 2211.2 7515) (12.1212 4567.01 111.111, 123.123 456.456 789.789, 7515 71315.125 0))"
```

Is there a way to quickly remove the third number from every comma separated set? This data is coming in as string, so I'm guessing some kind of complex RegEx magic to select and then remove it?

EDIT:

Sorry I forgot to put in my desired output! It should be like this:

```
"((123.456 456.321, 1122.1 2211.2) (12.1212 4567.01, 123.123 456.456, 7515 71315.125))"
```

Comment: Please read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Comment: By "the third number" do you mean something like: 789.123, or do you mean (like in the third parenthesized set): 7515 71315.125 0. Like are you expecting the output to be:

"((123.456 456.321, 1122.1 2211.2) (12.1212 4567.01, 123.123 456.456, 7515 71315.125))" 

or

"((123.456 456.321 789.123, 1122.1 2211.2 7515) (12.1212 4567.01 111.111, 123.123 456.456 789.789))".

Also, as you mention, the input is a string. Is the output a string?

Comment: What kind of data is this? how do you parse/use it? couldn't you just ignore the third value at that place?

Comment: Please post a sample of the  desired **output**

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use something like:

```js
my_string = "((123.456 456.321 789.123, 1122.1 2211.2 7515) (12.1212 4567.01 111.111, 123.123 456.456 789.789, 7515 71315.125 0))";
result = my_string.replace(/\(([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+)\)/g, "($1,$2)");
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
my_string = "((123.456 456.321 789.123, 1122.1 2211.2 7515) (12.1212 4567.01 111.111, 123.123 456.456 789.789, 7515 71315.125 0))";
result = my_string.replace(/((?:[0-9]+)(?:\.[0-9]+)? (?:[0-9]+)(?:\.[0-9]+)?) ([0-9]+)(\.[0-9]+)?/g, "$1");
console.log(result);
```